# Creating a function to check if a JS element exists

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, referenceerror

I find myself checking to see if javascript elements exist a lot using:

```
if (typeof elem == "undefined")
  // Do something
```

I want to create a function so I can reduce code repetition.

```
if (exists(elem))
```

Here is the function I created:

```
if (typeof exists == 'undefined') {
    function exists (e)
    {
        if (typeof e == "undefined")
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is the variable is undefined before it goes through the function. It generates a javascript error. How do I create a function to handle this?

Comment: Off topic a bit, but you shouldn't declare a function inside a statement block. It's illegal, though not enforced by all implementations. In *strict mode*, trying to do that will throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"The problem is the variable is undefined before it goes through the function. It generates a javascript error."*

By *"undefined"*, I assume you mean *"undeclared"*, therefore causing a `ReferenceError`.

If so, you would need to test to see if it exists before you pass it to the function, which makes the function rather pointless.

Rather than trying to  create a function to test for undeclared variables, simply declare them before using them.

IMO, `typeof x === 'undefined'` is an ugly hack that shouldn't be necessary. You should consider the `ReferenceError` to be a friend that is telling you something needs fixing. The `typeof` hack prevents your friend from telling you what's going on.

Comment: +1 agree with the "ugly hack" bit, don't know why that hadn't come to me sooner ... so prevalent - i guess...

Comment: @Xander: Yeah, I really think it's unfortunate. It's only avoiding problems that should be solved elsewhere.